# Need clarification on some Cisco configurations

Tags: cisco, trunk, etherchannel, cisco-2960

Here is the situation : 
I have an HP server with 2 network interfaces linked to a Cisco switch. I want to configure the switch to accept the NIC teaming of the server. I have always believed that the "trunk" mode is to carry vlans from a switch to another one (or router). But I saw some configurations of ports linked to server with active LACP (or etherchannel) and in trunk mode.

So my question is: what is the difference (port of server) between `switchport mode acces vlan 1, 2, 3` and `switchport trunk allowed vlan 1, 2, 3`?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "switchport mode acces vlan 1, 2, 3"

A switchport in access mode will be associated with a unique VLAN and the packet leaving the port will be untagged. 
(Well, if you use a voice VLAN you will actually have 2 VLAN, one tagged and the other untagged)

In trunk mode it can carry as many VLAN as you want, and all packet will be tagged with the appropriate VLAN tag, except optionally for a VLAN marked as native.

Comment: So, for the ports connected to my server, they need to be configured in trunk mode if i want the server in several VLAN ?

Comment: yes but this requires that you server be configured accordingly